# Can't see JDialog components when calling from another JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

i would like to know how can i see the components in my JDialog when calling it from another one.

I have one jDialog called Cargando1 which has a ProgressBar inside,this jDialog runs a method called iterate() when loading.

Otherwise i have another jDialog called login1, it has a button called btnIngresar, it validates some user and password stuff and then it should call Cargando1.

Also cargando1 calls a Frame called Principal after the progressbar has reach 100% but it doesn't matter.

I would like to know why when i called Cargando1 from Login1 it runs but i can't see the components on it.

Thank you for helping me!

This is the Jdialog called Login1

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Login1 extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
private JLabel lblUsuario;
private JTextField txtUsuario;
private JPasswordField jpassContrasena;
private JLabel lblContrasena;
private JButton btnIngresar;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Login1 dialog = new Login1();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Create the dialog.
 */
public Login1() {
    setBounds(100, 100, 225, 157);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    lblUsuario = new JLabel("Usuario:");
    lblUsuario.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblUsuario.setBounds(10, 12, 80, 20);
    getContentPane().add(lblUsuario);

    txtUsuario = new JTextField();
    txtUsuario.setColumns(10);
    txtUsuario.setBounds(101, 11, 95, 20);
    getContentPane().add(txtUsuario);

    jpassContrasena = new JPasswordField();
    jpassContrasena.setBounds(101, 43, 95, 20);
    getContentPane().add(jpassContrasena);

    lblContrasena = new JLabel("Contrase\u00F1a:");
    lblContrasena.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblContrasena.setBounds(10, 44, 80, 20);
    getContentPane().add(lblContrasena);

    btnIngresar = new JButton("Ingresar");
    btnIngresar.addActionListener(this);
    btnIngresar.setBounds(60, 80, 90, 23);
    getContentPane().add(btnIngresar);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if (arg0.getSource() == btnIngresar) {
        actionPerformedBtnIngresar(arg0);
    }
}
protected void actionPerformedBtnIngresar(ActionEvent arg0) {
    char contrasena[] = jpassContrasena.getPassword();
    String contrasenadef = new String(contrasena);
    if (txtUsuario.getText().equals("Administrador") && contrasenadef.equals("admin"))
    {   Principal.sesion = 'A';
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Bienvenido, administrador", "Mensaje de bienvenida", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        Cargando1 dialog = new Cargando1();
        this.dispose();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.iterate();

    }
    else if (txtUsuario.getText().equals("Vendedor") && contrasenadef.equals("vendedor"))
    {   Principal.sesion = 'V';
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Bienvenido, vendedor", "Mensaje de bienvenida", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        Cargando1 dialog = new Cargando1();
        this.dispose();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.iterate();

    }
    else
    {   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor ingrese un usuario y/o contraseña correctos", "Acceso denegado", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
}
```

This is the JDialog called cargando1

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class Cargando1 extends JDialog {

private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
private JProgressBar pgbCargando;
int porcentaje=0;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Cargando1 dialog = new Cargando1();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.iterate();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Create the dialog.
 */
public Cargando1() {
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 154);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPanel.setLayout(null);

    pgbCargando = new JProgressBar(0,2000);
    pgbCargando.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 93);
    pgbCargando.setStringPainted(true);
    contentPanel.add(pgbCargando);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(true);
    setContentPane(contentPanel);
}

 void iterate() {

      while (porcentaje < 2000)
      { pgbCargando.setValue(porcentaje);
        try {Thread.sleep(100);}
        catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        porcentaje += 95;
      }
        Principal formulario1 = new Principal();
        formulario1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.dispose();
        formulario1.setVisible(true);
      }

}
```

Comment: I don't see a setVisible(true) for Cargando1.

Comment: Make `setVisible(true);`in `Cargando1` the last thing you call - Swing is lazy when it comes to updating the UI and it requires you to inform it when it should perform a layout/paint pass

Comment: `iterate` is also going to cause you issues as Swing is single threaded AND not thread safe

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the iterate() method.  Change your iterate() method to the following and give it a try.

```
void iterate() {
    final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (porcentaje < 2000) {
                pgbCargando.setValue(porcentaje);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                }
                porcentaje += 95;
            }
        }
    });
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}
```

This will free up the main thread to do gui updates while the ProgressBar's value is modified in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to fix(and a note for the future):

1. Use `Cargando1.setVisible(true)` in `Cargando1`
2. DO NOT use `Thread.sleep` for swing, because `javax.swing` is not thread-safe. Your `JDialog` will freeze if you use `Thread.sleep`. Rather, use a [`Timer(javax.swing)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) with an `ActionListener`, or if you really want to use `Thread.sleep`, look into multithreading.

<sub>3. please indent better!!!! usually a new line with an extra 4 spaces after every `{`</sub>

Comment: Neither your statement (1) nor your statement (2) is true for the bug demonstrated in the supplied example.

Comment: @Java42 How so?

Comment: 1) setVisible() is not needed in his action listener.  2) It is perfectly fine to use Thread.sleep() in a swing application.

Comment: @Java42 1) Your right, I fixed my answer -  2) I said that he had to multithread if he wanted to use Thread.sleep. I clarified my answer